# React Native Array not working when passed as props to child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component which contains an array, and I want to pass this array down to a child component and use map to render items based on the elements of that array. However, when trying to use map with the array, React does not seem to recognize the prop as an array, because I get the following error:

Undefined is not an object ('Evaluating this.props.foodTagList.map')

So it thinks map is an object and not a function...

In short, Parent:

```
const food = { TagList:[
    {
        TagId: 4,
        TagName: "onion"
    },
    {
        TagId: 6,
        TagName: "beef"
    },
    {
        TagId: 7,
        TagName: "pork"
    },
    {
        TagId: 8,
        TagName: "carrot"
    },
    {
        TagId: 9,
        TagName: "fish"
    }
]};

<FoodTags foodTagList={food.TagList} />
```

And Child:

```
export default class FoodTags extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    return false;
}

render(){
    return <View style={layoutStyles.tagWrapper}>
        {this.props.foodTagList.map((x, i) => {
            return( <Tag key={i} info={this.props.foodTagList[i]} />)
        })}
    </View>
}
```

}

```
class Tag extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

render(){
    return <Text style={foodStyles.tag}>{this.props.info.TagName}</Text>
}
```

}

So my question is really: How do I correctly pass down arrays to child components?

Comment: Well it's a typo that I made when writing the question. It's not present in my code and is obviously not the source of the error. The problem persists. When I pass an array as a prop, the child no longer views it as an array.

And by the way. Using x[i] instead of this.props.foodTagList[i] does not work either.

Comment: are you fetching the data from server or it's hardcoded ? don't use `info={this.props.foodTagList[i]}` use `info={x}` index is not required with x.

Comment: "So it thinks map is an object and not a function..." no it thinks that `this.props.foodTagList` is `undefined`.  Specify property types of `FoodTags` component `static propTypes = {foodTagList: PropTypes.array.isRequired}` to see which component passes incorrect props.

Comment: @SimonEliasson The code looks like it should work. You really need to work out where the undefined is as it could be on `props.foodTagList`, can you let me know the result of `this.props.foodTagList.isArray()`?

Comment: @SimonEliasson don't use `info={this.props.foodTagList[i]}` use `info={x}` index is not required with `x`, because `x` will a an `object` (each object of that array)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Learned a lot. I will delete the post. I tested with the x syntax and fiddled around with proptypes and suddenly it worked. But I can't pinpoint exactly what was the solution, because when I undid the changes it still works. So probably I had some syntax wrong somewhere. Sorry for wasting your time, but the comments you left still helped me fix it, so thanks!

Undeleted it. I don't know what should be done though.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that `foodTagList` is actually `undefined` when you initially render and because you have `return false` you are not getting the data at all. If it thinks that `map` is an object and not a function you'll get `Uncaught TypeError: map is not a function` or something like this. Can you try return `true` in `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate was not the issue in this case.